# Making front matter parameter text bold in hugo

Tags: markdown, hugo, toml

I was wondering if there's a way to make some phrases bold on my markdown file parameters (TOML). I'm using one of the parameters to render a text description on a page, it loads perfectly but visually I need to highlight parts of the text to make it easier to read.

I need it to be something like this:

```
---
 title: "page title"
 description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **consectetur adipiscing** elit, sed do eiusmod."
 date: ""
---
```

So it can be rendered:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **consectetur adipiscing** elit, sed do eiusmod.

Obviously that's not gonna work... I've never needed this before, but for what I know, any text contained by "" is just rendered as plain text, so no markdown syntax works here.

Does anyone knows if there's a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using raw HTML? `description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing</strong> elit, sed do eiusmod."`

Comment: Yep, already tried it but no luck... It renders the tags. Maybe I should just approach what I'm trying to achieve differently.

Comment: Finally I've found the solution for my problem, you have to use this tag: {{.Description | markdownify}} The answer was always there but I just didn't read all the docs..... If you want to read more, check this out: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/bold-text-in-a-blog-post-description/4114

Comment: @eadas I'm having this same problem, but I'm new to markdown. Where do I put the tag `{{.Description | markdownify}}`?

Answer (score 0):

Hugo supports three formats for front matter, each with their own identifying tokens.

`TOML` identified by opening and closing `+++`

`YAML` identified by opening and closing `---`

`JSON` a single JSON object surrounded by ‘{’ and ‘}’, followed by a new line.

Either you must edit your tokens first, try again Or edit your question. :)